# Indexed manageable attributes in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I need to add a custom attributes to a class and make this attributes 'indexed'. This code fragment illustrates the issue:

```
import numpy as np

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = np.array([[100, 200, 300],
                             [100, 155, 120],
                             [300, 110, 333],
                             [500, 180, 120]
                            ], dtype='object')

    @property
    def SecondRow(self):
        return self.arr[:, 1]

    # Workaround which always works
    @SecondRow.setter
    def SecondRow(self, data):
        idx, value = data
        self.arr[idx][1] = value

def func(test):
    print(test.SecondRow)

    # It works sometimes (depending if python makes a copy of self.arr[:, 1] or not).
    # In the case of this example, it will work. In another context, it may not work.
    test.SecondRow[2] = 500
    print(test.arr)

    # It works always but the code is not neat. I would like it to look as in the previous example.
    test.SecondRow = (2, 600)
    print(test.arr)

test = Test()
func(test)
```

The output is:

```
[200 155 110 180]
[[100 200 300]
 [100 155 120]
 [300 500 333]
 [500 180 120]]
[[100 200 300]
 [100 155 120]
 [300 600 333]
 [500 180 120]]
```

Here the output is ok. However, in the real project arrays are huge and there are many intermediate calls between creating a 'class Test' instance and calling 'def func()' and in some cases python interpreter makes a copy of 'self.arr[:, 1]' (particularly problematic are unit tests) and changing it will not affect the actual numpy array 'self.arr' but just a copy of the column.

How can I address the [index] in a regular way (like test.SecondRow[2]) and still handle the copying issue?

I appreciate any help?

Comment: How about trying to prevent a copy by force, maybe something like `return self.arr[:, 1].view()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, view() did not help.

Comment: Another thing worth testing is whether doing `self.arr[:, 1:2]` instead of `self.arr[:, 1]` solves your issue. I think the former is supposed to enforce a view, while the latter might return a copy. See [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly hacky way to do what you want by piggybacking off `__setitem__`.

```
import numpy as np

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = np.array([[100, 200, 300],
                             [100, 155, 120],
                             [300, 110, 333],
                             [500, 180, 120]
                            ], dtype='object')
        
        # a control mechanism if there are multiple properties
        self.signal = None

    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        """Performs action according to specified signal."""
        
        if self.signal == "R1":
            self.arr[idx, 1] = value
        elif self.signal == "C0":
            self.arr[0, idx] = value
        
        self.signal = None # reset signal

    @property
    def SecondRow(self):
        self.signal = "R1"
        return self

    @property
    def FirstColumn(self):
        self.signal = "C0"
        return self
```

This should allow you to index into your custom property and modify your array without issues.

```
def func(test):
    test.SecondRow[2] = 500
    print("Arr:\n", test.arr)

    test.FirstColumn[0] = -17
    print("Arr:\n", test.arr)
    
test = Test()
func(test)
```

Output:

```
Arr:
 [[100 200 300]
 [100 155 120]
 [300 500 333]
 [500 180 120]]
Arr:
 [[-17 200 300]
 [100 155 120]
 [300 500 333]
 [500 180 120]]
```

#### Drawback

While `test.SecondRow[2] = 500` should work without any issues now, we've lost the ability to do `print(test.SecondRow)`, as we directly rout to self and setitem.